# Mark and Close?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When going through the close/re-open/first questions queue(s) - there are often times when I see a Question that has the potential to be a good question, but needs a little extra detail that only the OP can provide.

Now - there is obviously the option to close for needing more detail - however, the scenarios I'm talking about are where there is some healthy comments/questions in the comments of the Question and it's likely that the OP will read them questions and update the question.

There is also obviously the option to re-open a question as well.

However I feel there is a hesitancy to re-open a closed question when it comes to moderation and there's a degree of hesitancy to VTC a question that is in that borderline area (especially if, with the right detail, it has the potential to be a very *good* question).

What I'd like to see is an option to mark a question for close in 24 hrs if no edit has been made, with the OP notified as such.

I think that this highlights the need to update the question and allows the Moderator a '3rd option' for those who don't necessarily want to close but also think it needs work.

Comment: "there's a degree of hesitancy to VTC a question that is in that borderline area" - are you saying that you hesitate in that condition, or that folks in general hesitate? Because if it's the latter, I'm sure not seeing that. I often see a race to close questions by a certain group.

Comment: Most of the questions that get VTC though are pretty clearly ones that ought to be closed - and your right, there's no hesitation there - I'm thinking on questions like if there's a single key bit missing that turns it from a VTC question to a really good question.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see this as a moderation issue. As mods we rarely close anything except clearly unsuitable questions. We leave most close actions to the community.

We don't have any hesitation re-opening questions that warrant it either.

Comment: Mod is probably the wrong word - I'm talking about the Community actions (as I don't have Mod status)

Answer (score 4):

Feel free to edit/improve, and ask for clarification. When it's ready to be opened (as per your consideration), you can cast a reopen vote, and post here on Meta for a [reopen-request](/questions/tagged/reopen-request)

Unfortunately, some folks don't respond to the clarification request which causes the reopen effort/motion to fail.

Answer (score 1):

My concern is that a newcomer, after seeing a post closed, may not realize that that is a request to refine the question rather than a rejection of the question entirely. It would be nice if the clothes for editing request made that more explicit.

Meanwhile, I will often comment on the need for editing, and give them a chance to do so, before flagging it as needing to be closed for that reason.

So the tools exist to do this properly. But the system does not encourage us to do so. Unfortunately, that seems to be a basic stack exchange behavior, and not something we can fix here.